# Jquery load popup from external file

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, loading

I need to upload different text files each containing some popups.
I am using JQM 1.4.5 and I'm pretty sure I don't make any syntax errors.
My main program has a menu and the user can choose the text.
At this point, I have to upload the text file and the popup file related to that text.
All the attempts I've made using the '.load' function work for text but not for popups.
Can you give me some suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Popup Tooltip</title>

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
$(document).ready(function(){   
    
    $("#t1").click (function(){ 
        $("#corpus").load("text1/text1.html");
        $("#pp").load("text1/popup1.html #popupBasic").enhanceWithin();
        }); 

    $("#t2").click (function(){
        $("#corpus").load("text2/text2.html");
        $("#pp").load("text2/popup2.html");
    }); 
}); 
</script>   

<style type="text/css">
a:link {color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:100%;
}
#tableMax{
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin:0 auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
    }
#tableMax tr {border-bottom: 1px solid brown;  
    }
#tableMax td {padding: 18px 25px 18px 20px;
    font-family: "Didot";
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    color:black;
    }
#tableMax td:nth-child(1) {  
  color:brown;
  font-size:100%;
  text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
     <div data-role="content">
    <div id="menu" style="display:block;">
        <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline" id="t1">text 1</button>
        <br>
        <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline" id="t2">text 2</button>
    </div>

    <div id="corpus"></div> 
    <div data-role="popup" id="pp"></div>
    
    </div>  <!-- chiude content -->
</div>

</body>
</html>

<!-- text1.html> -->
<table id="tableMax">
    <tr><td>1a</td>
    <td>This text contains a <a href="#popup_1a" data-rel="popup"> popup</a>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>1b</td>
    <td>This text also contains a <a href="#popup_1b" data-rel="popup"> popup</a>
    </td></tr>
</table>

<!-- popup1.html  -->
<p id="popup_1" style="background:lightgreen; color:#000; max-width:500px;">
    This is the content of popup 1a.</p>

<p id="popup_2" style="background:lightgreen; color:#000; max-width:500px;">
    This is the content of popup 1b.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to achieve what You want:

- Basically, IMHO it is better *not* to create and destroy again and
  again a JQM widget. If possible, create just at the beginning all
  needed widgets and change the *content*, i.e. *text* and *images*
  when You need it.

  In my example I will show You both: dynamic destroying and instancing
  a JQM table and dynamic changing the content of one existing popup.
  Please, note that for a JQM table the `thead` and `th` tags are mandatory.
- In Your example, You may need to show some data related to a table
  row, but in my example I will attach the popup data to a single cell.
  I believe, this is a more flexible approach.

  The simplest way to create such a relation is to set a custom
  data-attribute. You can call it whatever You want. Just for instance,
  *data-info*:  `<a href="#pp" data-rel="popup" data-info="#1a"> popup</a>`

  After that, the popup content will be retrieved from the clicked
  anchor, just before the popup will be open.
- For the menu, instead of *push-buttons* I am using *radio-buttons*,
  so the code will be much simpler, using just one event handler.
- Moreover, it will be nice if You tell the user that something is
  going on, by using a spinner and a visual feedback after the table
  data has been downloaded (table *fade-in*).

Here is the most relevant code:

```
$(document)
  .ready(function () {
    $('input[name=files]').on('change', function (e) {
      var path = e.target.id, $table = $("#tableMax").hide().table("destroy");
      $.mobile.loading("show");
      $.when($.get(path + '/popup.html'), $.get(path + '/text.html')).done(
        function (popupData, tableData) {
          $.mobile.loading("hide");
          /* each data[0] will contain the response text */
          $table.html(tableData[0]).table({create: function() { 
            var allPopups = $('<div></div>').append(popupData[0]);
            $(this).fadeIn("slow").data("mobile-table").allHeaders.each(function() {
              $(this).data("cells").each(function(){
                $(this).find("a[href='#pp']").each(function () {
                  var popupLink = $(this).attr("data-info"),
                      popupContent = $(allPopups).find(popupLink);
                  $(this).data("popup-content", popupContent);
                });
              });
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  })
  .on('pagebeforechange', function (e, ui) {
    var link = ui.options.link, ctx = link && link.context, hash = ctx && ctx.hash;
    if (hash == '#pp') $(hash).empty().html($(ctx).data('popup-content'));
  });
```

Here is a full workng **DEMO**: https://plnkr.co/edit/3IXDqQJMVn2QYOed?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: Your code is perfect and exactly meets my needs. Many thanks.